# Rolling a kasaya

Tags: tibetan-buddhism

I am trying to wear my kasaya while awaiting temporary ordination.

I have watched some videos but I seem to be getting stuck after finding the center point and rolling towards me. When I try to put my left arm in and extend it out I’m getting stuck with not enough or too much fabric too, I can’t seem to make it work.

Does anyone have any resources?

For reference, I have watched these videos a lot:

https://youtu.be/YRRzKneG238

https://youtu.be/5mAQa2BOvRw

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9RwqLJo5_-c&t=92s